# Selecting all elements of many-to-many x will result in duplicates in many-to-many y

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've ran into this weird problem, hopefully someone can help me out.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong or overlooked something??

Whenever I select all n materials the models I've selected are listed n times.
Vice versa when I select all n models the materials are listed n times.

For example: Material1 (selected)
Material2 (selected)
Material3 (selected)

Model1 (selected)
Model2
Model3

Results in:

Material1
Material2
Material3

Model1
Model1
Model1

I'm using Spring 4.0.3, Spring Data JPA 1.4.3, Hibernate 4.3.1, MySQL 5.1.28, Thymeleaf 2.1.2
The posted DTO is correct, containing only the selected materials and models.
The data in the database is also correct!

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "SKUS")
public class Sku extends BaseEntityAudit {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
    protected String code;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "RETAIL_PRICE", nullable = true)
    protected BigDecimal retailPrice;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "SKU_MODELS",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MODEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    protected List<SkuModel> availableModels;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "SKU_MATERIALS",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MATERIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    protected List<Material> availableMaterials;

    public static Builder getBuilder(String code, String name) {
        return new Builder(code, name);
    }

    public void update(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void updatePrice(BigDecimal retailPrice) {
        this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
    }

    public void updateMaterials(List<Material> materials) {
        if (!materials.equals(availableMaterials)) {
            this.availableMaterials.clear();
            this.availableMaterials = materials;
        }
    }

    public void updateModels(List<SkuModel> models) {
        if (!models.equals(availableModels)) {
            this.availableModels.clear();
            this.availableModels = models;
        }
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Sku built;

        public Builder(String code, String name) {
            built = new Sku();
            built.code = code;
            built.name = name;
        }

        public Builder retailPrice(BigDecimal retailPrice) {
            built.retailPrice = retailPrice;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder models(List<SkuModel> models) {
            built.availableModels = models;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder materials(List<Material> materials) {
            built.availableMaterials = materials;
            return this;
        }

        public Sku build() {
            return built;
        }
    }
}

public interface SkuRepository extends JpaRepository<Sku, Long> {}

// SkuService
@Transactional(readOnly = true, rollbackFor = {NotFoundException.class})
@Override
public Sku findById(Long id) throws NotFoundException {
    LOGGER.debug("Finding a sku entry with id: {}", id);

    Sku found = skuRepository.findOne(id);
    LOGGER.debug("Found sku entry: {}", found);

    if (found == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("No sku found with id: " + id);
    }

    return found;
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {NotFoundException.class})
@Override
public Sku update(SkuDTO updated) throws NotFoundException {
    LOGGER.debug("Updating sku with request information: {}", updated);

    Sku model = findById(updated.getId());

    model.update(updated.getCode(), updated.getName());
    model.updatePrice(updated.getRetailPrice());
    model.updateMaterials(updated.getMaterials());
    model.updateModels(updated.getModels());

    LOGGER.debug("Updating sku with information: {}", model);
    skuRepository.save(model);
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_SKU_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findById(@PathVariable(PARAMETER_SKU_ID) Long id, Model uiModel) throws NotFoundException {
    LOGGER.debug("Rendering sku page for sku entry with id: {}", id);

    Sku found = skuService.findById(id);
    LOGGER.debug("Found sku entry with information: {}", found);

    uiModel.addAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_SKU, found);

    return VIEW_SKU_DETAILS;
}

@RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAPPING_SKU_EDIT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processUpdateSkuForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_SKU) SkuDTO dto, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) throws NotFoundException {
    LOGGER.debug("Updating a sku entry with information: {}", dto);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        LOGGER.debug("Update sku entry form was submitted with validation errors. Redirecting back to form view.");
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult." + MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_SKU, result);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_SKU, dto);
        attributes.addAttribute(PARAMETER_SKU_ID, dto.getId());
        return createRedirectViewPath(REQUEST_MAPPING_SKU_EDIT);
    }

    Sku updated = skuService.update(dto);
    LOGGER.debug("Updated the information of a sku entry to: {}", updated);

    attributes.addAttribute(PARAMETER_SKU_ID, updated.getId());
    return createRedirectViewPath(REQUEST_MAPPING_SKU_DETAILS);
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that 3 `model1` objects are being created? Or is it only listing `model1` 3 times?

Comment: It is listing model1 3 times while it's only one row in the jointable SKU_MODELS (sku_id, model_id) the SKU_MATERIALS table contains 3 rows (sku_id, material_id). Retrieving the Sku model results in 3 model1 objects in availableModels and material1,2 and 3 in availableMaterials

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

I believe this is because the Spring generated query doesn't use 'DISTINCT' when it does the join, but I don't know the solution. You might be able to use a Set<> instead of a List<>

Comment: any other solution so far apart from using Set ? :(